# How would one reference a property of an object when the property's name is not known?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a controller/view that receives a JSON response from a server.

The server returns an object that has many keys, but I won't know the name of some of them coming back since they are product ID's.  I don't have control over this response.

I need to display these properties in a template.  How would I refer to them without knowing the keys?

I was thinking about just building out a template string using `Ember.Handlebars.compile()` while looping over the object that I receive, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would format the data before passing it to the template, making some assumptions based on your question.

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return $.getJSON('foo').then(function(result){
      //format the data into something standard, key value pair or whatever it is
      return formattedResult;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm an idiot - that's exactly what I could do.  I think this question is more of a brainfart on my part.

Thank you.